# Better way to convert IP?

Tags: bash, shell-script, string

I am trying to convert `10.AB.C9.XYZ` to `10.AB.C2.252`.

Right now I am extracting each character and piecing them together.

```bash
ip_main=10.AB.C9.XYZ

A_char=${ip_main:3:1}
B_char=${ip_main:4:1}
C_char=${ip_main:6:1}

new_ip="10.${A_char}${B_char}.${C_char}2.252"
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want to do is to replace the last digit of the third octet and the whole of the fourth octet with `2.252`, then you may do that with

```bash
new_ip=${ip_main%?.*}2.252
```

This deletes the shortest suffix string from `$ip_main` that matches `?.*`, and then appends `2.252` to the result of that.  The substitution with this pattern will always affect the last digit of the third octet, the dot between the 3rd and 4th octets, and then the whole 4th octet.

Testing:

```bash
$ ip_main=10.AB.C9.XYZ
$ new_ip=${ip_main%?.*}2.252
$ printf '%s\n' "$new_ip"
10.AB.C2.252
```

Comment: what does mean the `%` character in `%?.*` ?

Comment: @OlivierBoissé It's what makes the substitution remove the shortest suffix that matches the pattern. Using `%%` would make it remove the _longest_ suffix.  In the same way, using `#` or `##` removes the shortest and longest _prefix_ respectively. This is a standard parameter substitution mechanics of all POSIX shells. See e.g. the `bash` manual or the POSIX standard: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02

Comment: @Kusalananda My understanding is that the pattern match is happening from right to left so `.` would match the last octet and `*` any character after the dot. I am confused about the `?`. It is a extended regular expression that means match zero or one time. Why is matching only one time here (C chracter) ?

Comment: @Cruise5 Yes, the pattern is matched at the end of the string due to `%`. The `*` matches any string and `.` matches the last dot. Since I use `%` (match _shortest_ suffix string) and not `%%` (match _longest_ suffix string), the `.*` pattern matches the last dot and the last octet. Had I used `%%`, then I would have matched the _first_ dot (after the 1st octet) and the rest of the string.  The `?` matches any single character. This is a shell globbing pattern and not a regular expression.

Comment: From Linux Command Line 2nd by William Shotts: Posix Basic vs. Extended Regular expressions: "What’s the difference between BRE and ERE? It’s a matter of metacharacters.

With BRE, the following metacharacters are recognized: `^ $ . [ ] *`
All other characters are considered literals. With ERE, the following
metacharacters (and their associated functions) are added: `( ) { } ? + |`

However (and this is the fun part), the (, ), {, and } characters are treated
as metacharacters in BRE if they are escaped with \, whereas with
ERE, preceding any metacharacter with \ makes it literal

Comment: @Cruise5 The pattern in my answer is not a regular expression. It is a shell pattern. This is the type of pattern used in filename globbing. The `?` matches a single character. See the chapter on "Wildcards" on page 24 of your book. Also the POSIX standard here: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13

Comment: @Kusalananda. How would I handle an IP that where C is two characters (ex. 01). For example: ip_main=10.AB.09.XYZ. The end result would be 10.AB.02.252 which is not desirable. I want to ignore the zero if it exists by accident in ip_main.

Comment: @Cruise5 That seems to be a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract 7 from the third octet, and replace the fourth:

```
echo 10.11.19.44 | awk -F. '{OFS=FS; print $1,$2,$3-7,252}'
10.11.12.252
```

This process would work most efficiently if you had a list of IP addresses to change.

Answer (score 0):

With `sed` :

```
sed 's/[^.][.][^.]*$/2.252/'
```

```bash
ip="10.AB.C9.XYZ"
echo "$ip" | sed 's/[^.][.][^.]*$/2.252/'
10.AB.C2.252
```