# IP address string manipulation problem

Tags: bash, shell-script, string

I am trying to build three octets `10.AB.C9` from a 5 digit number: `12ABC`:

- `12` = first octet
- `AB` = Second octet
- `C` = Third octet

There are two scenarios with my existing code that can cause an in correct IP to generate.
If C has a leading zero for example: 02 then the third octet will 027 and IPs can't have hardcoded leading zeros.

```
five_digits=12620

if [ "${five_digits:4:1}" -eq 0 ]; then
  ip_main="10.${five_digits:2:2}.9"
  gateway_ip_prefix="10.${five_digits:2:2}.2"

elif [ "${five_digits:4:1}" -ne 0 ]; then
  
  ip_main="10.${five_digits:2:2}.${five_digits:4:1}9"
  gateway_ip_prefix="10.${five_digits:2:2}.${five_digits:4:1}2"
```

The above code solves the leading zero problem in C

The second scenario is where A is zero meaning the second octet will have a leading zero. I am not sure how to handle that scenario and hopefully make the script simpler.

Comment: "IPs can't have hardcoded leading zeros" -- why not? You'd be surprised at what _else_ `inet_aton()` in particular accepts... The most common way of presenting IPv4 addresses has four groups though, so I'm not sure what `10.AB.C9` is supposed to be. Do you mean those letters are just placeholders for some digits, and the digits themselves are constant? So that you have a five-digit input string, want to drop the `12` from the start, and then stuff the three remaining digits in between `10.`, `.` and `9`? (The problem is that `10.AB.C9` looks like three two-digit hex numbers separated by dots.)

Comment: if those are decimal numbers, your five-digit input can't represent IPs with octets > 99, a rather big part of the value range of each octet

Comment: ABC are place holders for numbers that go into the first three octets. The last octet is add later in the script. For example if ABC are `860`, then first three octets of IP would look like `10.86.09` but I want them to be `10.86.9`. I think my script handles that. If ABC would be `055` then first three octets would be `10.05.5` but I want it to look like `10.5.5`

Comment: Is this related to [Better way to convert IP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/707393/100397)? It certainly looks like it

Comment: @roaima Yes it is but it's asking a different question and I am not allowed to ask a different question in the comments there.

Comment: You've got five digits 12ABC, so C can only be a single digit. So how can you possibly get the situation "_If C has a leading zero for example: 02_"?

Comment: @roaima The relevant information I forgot to put in 12 is first octet, AB is second octet and C is third octet.

Comment: Cruise5 if you leave it just in the comments it'll likely get missed. Please always [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/708032/edit) to include updated/corrected/additional information. But I still don't see how a five digit number `12ABC` can leave you with two digits for `C`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would break each octet apart, and remove any leading zeroes from each, then concatenate them together. Something like this:

```
str="$five_digits"
if [[ ${#str} != 5 ]] || [[ ${str:0:2} != "12" ]]; then
    echo invalid input >&2;
    exit 1;
fi
a=10               # first octet, constant
b=${str:2:2}       # second octet
b=${b#0}           # remove one leading zero
c=${str:4:1}9      # third octet
c=${c#0}           # remove one leading zero

res="$a.$b.$c"     # concatenated result
echo "$res"
```

E.g. that turns the input string `12345` to `10.34.59`; `12055` to `10.5.59`; and `12000` to `10.0.9`.

Comment: The five_digits won't be a position argument though so can I remove `local` before str and put in the global `five_digit` variable?. It will be a variable defined earlier in the script. Also the result of echo needs to be saved in variable on which I can do further manipulation.

Comment: @Cruise5, yeah, you don't need to make a function (edit). Or you could make it a function and assign the result to any (global) variable.